How does indirect expansion support further expansions?
The bash manual states that the expanded value of an indirect parameter expansion undergoes further expansions. I'm not finding that to be true. Can someone explain how it works?
3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion:

The value is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

Considerations that clearly don't work:
> a='$(echo b)'; echo "${!a}"
bash: $(echo b): invalid variable name
> a='b'; b='$(echo c)'; echo "${!a}"
$(echo c)
> a="b"; b="c"; echo "${!$a}"
bash: ${!$a}: bad substitution
> a="b"; b="c"; echo "${!!a}"
bash: ${!!a}: bad substitution
> a='$b'; b='c'; echo "${!a}"
bash: $b: invalid variable name
> a='!b'; b='c'; echo "${!a}"
bash: !b: invalid variable name

Another post shows that array indices are indeed expanded, e.g.
x='a[$(ls>&2)]'
echo "${!x}"

So how are the above value expansions implemented? Are they indeed limited to the 'value' of indirect parameter expansions, as it is described in the paragraph about it? Or perhaps does this further value expansion apply to all parameter expansions? Or is this strictly limited to array indices? What am I missing in understanding here? I'm failing to find examples of any value being expanded unless it's an array index.
Side note, if this works (a='b[@]'; echo "${!a}"), I would think a='!b'; echo "${!a}" should work, but doesn't. Apparently this has to be used (a="${!b}"; echo "${!a}").

how are the above value expansions implemented? like so https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/subst.c#L7628 .

maybe a='b[$(echo 123 >&2)]'; b='val'; echo ${!a} is meant by further expensions

Consider a=b; b=foo; printf "%s\n" "${!a:0:2}"

$(echo b) is a form of command substitution not parameter expansion and in indirect expansions you reference "valid parameter references"; not those having $ in them already. x='a[$(ls>&2)]'; echo "${!x}" works because index expressions are interpreted in another level. See valid_array_reference.
